# customizing location of last row of a series of subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have generated this figure below ( i cut the text on the top because it is not relevant).

[image]

the first two rows share a colorbar, the last one is different. As you see I know how to create a cax and place it below the row I want. What I don't know how to do is to shift the rows of the subplot(s) up or down to avoid the overlap of text/plots/colorbar that now it is in between the second and third row of figures.
In this case I want to move a bit down the last row so that it looks better.

any hints?

Comment: If you still want to keep the middle color bar at the same place, what you have to do is to add some spacing between your plots.  `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1)`  might be a starting value.

Comment: Thanks - yes I could do that. I would prefer having more space between row 2 and 3. I tried using     pos = get(gca(), 'position') and    set(gca(), 'position', pos)    but it doesn't seem to work - I think because I am using also basemap.

Comment: Are you using `plt.subplots(4, 3)` or some other fancy tool to create your grid?  The most flexible way (although most annoying as well) would be to add each axis separately with `fig.add_axes`.  Here is an example how to do it: http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html

Comment: yes - nothing super fancy, simply plt.subplot. fig.add_axes seems the way to go. I will try and see if it works with basemap.

Comment: It should be fairly straight forward since the width/height is the same, and for each row/column the x/y values are the same.  Create a list of coordinates for lower-left corner and loop over it.

Comment: I think pathoren's answer is simplest because your problem is nicely organized to start with, but for a more finicky problem check out gridspec: http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html